# SQL query for generating given data

Tags: sql

I have a table called student with two columns:

```
JoinDate DATE
EmployeeName STRING
```

The contents of the table are as follows:

```
EmployeeName    | JoinDate
----------------+-----------------
jaison          | 1-jan-2008
robin           | 2-feb-2008
binoy           | 3-mar-2008
rahul           | 4-feb-2008
```

I am looking to prepare the following output based on this table: a table containing 4-columns with names jan,feb,mar,april. Beneath each of these months a count is given as 1,2,1,0. These counts represent the number of employees that joined in that month (January 1 employee, February 2 employees, March 1 employee, April 0 employees)

Can you give me the required SQL query?

Comment: No thats an interview question

Comment: If it's an interview question, then maybe you should figure it out for yourself. The company that's interviewing you wouldn't want to hire you under the false assumption that you know what you're doing, right?

Comment: Do we need temperory table here

Comment: Any way i did that in different way in sql 2008,,i posted by answer this question.Any one know any other way,,Thanks

Comment: This can be simple done with using a PIVOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, anyone know any other way?

```
SELECT Sum([1]) AS Jan, Sum([2]) AS Feb, Sum([3]) AS Mar, Sum([4]) as Apr,
       Sum([5]) as May, Sum([6]) as Jun, Sum([7]) as Jul, Sum([8]) as Aug,
       Sum([9]) as Sep, Sum([10]) as Oct, Sum([11]) as Nov, Sum([12]) as Dec
FROM (SELECT Month(Join_Date) as Mon FROM student) ps
PIVOT
    (Count(Mon) FOR Mon IN 
        ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
    ) AS pvt
GROUP BY [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you a result set of two columns (month and total), where month is the month name and total is the number of people that joined that month:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`join_date`) AS `month`, COUNT(*) AS `total` GROUP BY MONTHNAME(`join_date`);
```

Comment: 'MONTHNAME' is not a recognized built-in function name in sql rite

Comment: It's a function in MySQL - the original poster didn't mention his database package. My query is based off an assumption.

Comment: i am working on sql server 2008,,Do we need temperory table here

Comment: Any way Thanks 4 replay ,i dont know abt mysql syntax,tas y i didnt check,,

Comment: Any way i did that in different way in sql 2008,,i posted by answer this question.Any one know any other way,,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This also will work

```
Create table [sample] (Employeename varchar(50), join_date smalldatetime)
insert into [sample] values('Ganesh','01/26/2008')
insert into [sample] values('Ramesh','02/26/2008')
insert into [sample] values('Dinesh','03/26/2008')
insert into [sample] values('Suresh','01/26/2008')

Select * from [sample]

SELECT 'Students Admission by Monthwise' ,[1] AS january,[2] AS february,[3] AS March,[4] AS April
FROM( 
        SELECT  Employeename,
                Month(join_date) monthname 
        FROM    [sample]
    ) A
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Employeename)
    FOR monthname in
        ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) AS PVT
```